# How can I Fade out an element with two conditionals (.scrollTop > X && screen.width < 600)

Tags: jquery, css

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
       if($(window).scrollTop() < 450){
             $('#logo').stop(true,true).fadeIn(1000);
       } else {
             $('#logo').stop(true,true).fadeOut(1000);
       }
    });
```

This is what I have at the moment. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why would you want to fade out a logo which will not be visible anyway once you scroll down? and also please post your html

Comment: Use : `if(cond1 === someval1 && cond2 === someval2) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var screenWidth = $(window).width();
   var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
   if(scrollTop < 450 && screenWidth < 600){
         $('#logo').stop(true,true).fadeIn(1000);
   } else {
         $('#logo').stop(true,true).fadeOut(1000);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```
   if($(window).scrollTop() < 450){
       $('#logo').stop(true,true).fadeIn(1000);
   } else if ( ( $(window).scrollTop() > X ) && ( screen.width < Y ) ) {
       // do your stuff
   } else {
       $('#logo').stop(true,true).fadeOut(1000);
   }
```